# error: unknown switch `a' caused by git

Tags: debian, docker, git

I have got the following error

```
Step 5/6 : RUN git clone https://github.com/jkimlab/mySyntenyPortal.git     cd mySyntenyPortal     find . -name '*.pl' -exec sed -i.bak 's|#!/usr/bin/perl|#!/usr/bin/env perl|' {} +
 ---> Running in a8c56b946874
error: unknown switch `a'
usage: git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]
```

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stretch-backports

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt update && apt install -y \
        build-essential \
        zlib1g-dev \
        locales \
        git

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && apt-get clean

RUN git clone https://github.com/jkimlab/mySyntenyPortal.git \
    cd mySyntenyPortal \
    find . -name '*.pl' -exec sed -i.bak 's|#!/usr/bin/perl|#!/usr/bin/env perl|' {} +

#./install.pl build

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git`, `cd`, and `find` are separate commands and need to be separated with `&&`, just like the `RUN` commands above.